# Problem overriding shouldComponentUpdate of PureComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, overriding

For example I want to write something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
    return super.shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext);
  }
}
```

But super.shouldComponentUpdate is undefined.

1. Why super.shouldComponentUpdate is undefined?
2. How to call default implementation of PureComponent?

React 16.0.0

Comment: @Ted for example i need to log this method, log result of shouldComponentUpdate, log what exact props differ, or i can remove some props that i want to ignore while comparing - there could be lots of reasons.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) PureComponent actually [doesn't](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/d7157651f7b72d9888c0123e191f9b88cd8f41e9/src/renderers/shared/stack/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L918) implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, so React docs are [lying](https://5a046bf5a6188f4b8fa4938a--reactjs.netlify.com/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

2) Close to default implementation:

```
import shallowEqual from 'fbjs/lib/shallowEqual'; // no need to install

class MyComponent extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
    return !shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !shallowEqual(this.state, nextState);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the PureComponent it is equivalent to implementing shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow comparison of current and previous props and state.
But if you want to write shouldComponentUpdate() by hand, you can inherit from React.Component.

Comment: how this answers my question?

Comment: The PureComponent doesn't declare the shouldComponentUpdate. You can't visit it with this.shouldComponentUpdate or super. In the React source code there is a shouldUpdate variable.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but i already found sources and wrote the same in the answer, with actualy answers to both my questions, which i don't see in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To further expand on Victor's response. The difference between a PureComponent and Component in react is a pure component handles shouldComponentUpdate by doing a shallow comparison of props and state.

If you're wanting to provide a custom shouldComponentUpdate to handle when and when not a component should update I would recommend just using a regular component. I would also make note that both PureComponent and Component both require a constructor that makes the super() call as the first line.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov In what way does it not? If by using a regular component, you will be able to use shouldComponentUpdate. This will allow you to look at the previous props as the first arg, and previous state as the second argument.

Comment: simple, just read question and try find answer. 1) why super.shouldComponentUpdate is undefined? 2) How to call default implementation of PureComponent?

Comment: And you are also wrong about constructor, it is not required.